# Highcharts click event on dataLabel which is using HTML

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So here's the issue .. 
I have used an image to represent the datalabels in a chart, and i need to set the 
'useHTML' flag to true in order to do that ..

But if i set the flag to true it does not allow me to bind click events to the datalabels ..
is there any way to get around this ..

Heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kodeNinja/hw6GB/200/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `onClick` handler this way:

```
$(chartObj.series[0].data[6].dataLabel.div.lastChild).bind('click', function(e) {
    alert('clicked!')
})
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hw6GB/201/).